# How to zip only files under multiple subdirectories?

Tags: shell, command-line, zip

I have a folder `working` and its structure is something like this -

```
working/
  100/
      1/
      2/
      3/
  200/
      1/
      2/
      3/
  300/
      1/
      2/
      3/
```

And each of these `1` `2` `3` folders have around 1000 files.

I want to zip the files under the `1` `2` `3` folders separately. The zip should not contain their top directories. Put the zips wherever they are. Such as, if there are files `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` under folder `1` then it should form a zip under `1` which should just have the foo files.

Comment: What should happen if there are more than the 1000 files in a subdirectory? Or did you mean that you want a single zip per folder of all the files in that folder?

Comment: Is it enough for you `tar -lzip --no-wildcards-match-slash -c -f arch.zip working/*/` ?

Comment: @roaima no, number of files don't matter. Yes I meant whatever you said the next. This - I want to zip the files under each of the `1` `2` `3` folders. Such as, if there are files `foo1` `foo2` and `foo3` under folder `1` then it should form a zip under `1` which should **just** have the `foo` files. @Costas, i want to `zip` them strictly. You sure this'll work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop will do the trick.

```
cd working
for dir in */*/; do
  [ -e "$dir/files.zip" ] ||   # skip directories where the zip already exists
  ( cd -- "$dir" && zip -r files.zip .)
done
```

Note that zip is smart enough to skip the zip file that is being built when recursing in that directory. Some other archiving programs would attempt to stuff the archive being built into the archive that's being built.

Comment: Awesome! But one thing. There is a zip called 'flashify.zip' which should go into the zip too. Also, I think there's need for `maxdepth` or something because there are folders under `1` `2` `3`. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @ChinmayKunkikar If `flashify.zip` is in the directory then it'll be included in the zip, otherwise it won't be included, just like you specified in the question. If you want to include another file in the zip, you can add it, e.g. `zip "$dir/files.zip" flashify.zip` if `flashify.zip` is located in `working`.

Comment: @ChinmayKunkikar What do you mean by “there's need for `maxdepth`” — do you mean that `100/1` and so on have subdirectories and that you don't want to include them in the zip? Then you can change `zip -r files.zip .` to `zip -D files.zip *` (this will omit dot files as well). Next time, include all your requirements in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I simply didn't noticed the `*/*;` . I got what I wanted. Thanks a lot.